# Multi-module Maven project builds continuously in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a number of multi-module Maven projects all of which build continously. This is a well-known problem but none of the suggested solutions have helped.

- Turn off `Project->Build Automatically`, `Project->Clean...`
- Check `.project` for multiple `maven2Builder` entries

The project structure is

```
parent
  +--model (jar)
  +--client (jar)
  +--restservice (war)
```

Both `client` and `restservice` have dependencies on `model`. These 2 modules build continuously but, as far as I can, tell they do not cause any changes in the `model` module.

Is there any way to track down what is causing this? Is there any tracing which might indicate what the trigger is?

**Update**

- I have executed the parent POM in a terminal and this runs successfully
- The *Maven Workspace View* shows all modules are continuously being built. The parent has no `execution` but has a `delta` which lists artifacts from all child modules

[image: Maven Workspace View]

**UPDATE**

I have created a bare-bones example on github https://github.com/pramsden/openapiproblem which demonstates the endless build-loop problem.

Comment: I would try to detect if there are any changes to the `model` module on file-system level using OS dependent tools (Process Monitor on Windows, inotify-tools on Linux). May be Eclipse is not the problem at all and a third party program running in background is causing this trouble?

Comment: The _Maven Workspace Build_ view is for this purpose.

Comment: Does building from the command line work? Can you show the three `pom.xml` files?

Comment: @howlger can you point me to a description of how the `Maven Workspace Build` view can be used to identify the triggers? Are the files listed in `delta` the files which cause the build of that project?

Comment: Yes, any of these file changes shown in the _Maven Workspace Build_ view, including touching a file without changing its content, triggers a new project build: https://www.eclipse.org/lists/m2e-users/msg04748.html Does the problem persist when you press the _Suspend_ button in the upper right?

Comment: @dan1st I have put them on github: https://github.com/pramsden/openapiproblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been caused by the openapi code generation in the modules. The parent detected changes and triggered a rebuild.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960032/11249 and I added the following to the parent POM:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- prevents generated code from triggering a rebuild -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[0.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>generate</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The Maven build executes just once and no further automatic builds are performed.